# IntelliJ Plugin Development: PluginException cannot create class Action

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea

I am working on an IntelliJ plugin in which I generate the Builder pattern. However, I cannot seem to use the plugin because of something called the PluginException. I reproduced the error in the same five steps as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764304/wizard-created-intellij-idea-plugin-throws-pluginexception-cannot-create-class), and because no answer is posted there I decided to give some code examples in this question (and I am not allowed to comment on the other question. That has a lot to do with it too).

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/koenwellens/IntelliJPluginTest/). The test-plugin should generate a field with a getter in the current class, and an inner class of a new type (NumberFactory). The stacktrace I get after installing the plugin is the following one:

```
*cannot create class "be.koen.wellens.MyBuilderGeneratorAction" [Plugin: be.koen.wellens]: cannot create class "be.koen.wellens.MyBuilderGeneratorAction" [Plugin: be.koen.wellens]
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: cannot create class "be.koen.wellens.MyBuilderGeneratorAction" [Plugin: be.koen.wellens]
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:287)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:239)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.getAction(ActionManagerImpl.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup.unStub(DefaultActionGroup.java:345)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup.getChildren(DefaultActionGroup.java:303)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl$5.compute(ActionManagerImpl.java:1261)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl$5.compute(ActionManagerImpl.java:1254)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:1254)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.preloadActionGroup(ActionManagerImpl.java:1248)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.generation.actions.GenerateAction.preload(GenerateAction.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:1266)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:1269)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.preloadActionGroup(ActionManagerImpl.java:1248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.c(ActionManagerImpl.java:1236)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.access$200(ActionManagerImpl.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl$4.run(ActionManagerImpl.java:1220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: be/koen/wellens/MyBuilderGeneratorAction : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 [Plugin: be.koen.wellens]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.b(PluginClassLoader.java:130)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.a(PluginClassLoader.java:77)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:262)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: be/koen/wellens/MyBuilderGeneratorAction : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:471)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:195)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:191)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:167)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.b(PluginClassLoader.java:124)
... 30 more*
```

Thanks in advance!

Koen

Comment: Use JDK 1.6 to compile the plugin http://stackoverflow.com/q/10382929

Answer (score 1):

The answer was given by Meo (thanks, Meo!). All I had to do was use JDK 1.6..
If only all things in life were that simple. :-)

Once more, thanks very much!